# Unusual "find" error in Typescript. Why ; is a problem?

Tags: typescript

What is the problem with this find here?

```js
let key = Object.keys(buyTicketData?.pricingOptions ?? {}).find(
  (key) =>
    buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?[key]?.name ===
    event.target.value
);
```

got this error:

```
ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx
./tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx 196:16-17
[tsl] ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx(196,17)
      TS1005: ':' expected.
 @ ./app/containers/Tiket/Test.tsx 2:0-148 36:88-133
 @ ./app/containers/Test.jsx 3:0-32 6:44-48
 @ ./app/shortcode35.js 8:0-46 14:54-63
```

and some interesting details, why `;` is problem?

```
onents/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx: Unexpected token (152:20)

  150 |                         event.target.value
  151 |                         :
> 152 |                     ;
      |                     ^
  153 |                 });
  154 |                 startPaymentIn2["pricingOptionId"] = key;
  155 |                 setStartPaymentIn(startPaymentIn2);
    at Object._raise (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:816:17)
```

and the types:

```
export type BuyTicketData = {
  pricingOptions?: PricingOptions;
}

export type PricingOptions = {
  [optionId: string]: PricingOptionType;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `?[]` right next to each other. You have to put a `.` in between like this:

`buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[key]?.name`

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions)

Comment: ahh, I forget :D